# Give ID's to dynamical elements

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, ajax

so:
I put some images in a list dynamically trough the JQuery.
I need to atrribute different ID's to each image because i want show the clicked image in another div.

Here's my JQ Code:

```
<script>

$.ajax({
    url: "Imagens/Trabalhos", //folder name
    success: function(data){
        var count = 0;
        $(data).find("a:contains(.jpg),a:contains(.png)").each(function(){
            // will loop through 
            var images = 'Imagens/Trabalhos/' +$(this).attr("href"); //get images names and set the path
            count++;
            var nome ='image'+count; //set the Suposed ID
            $('#ImageList').append('<li><a href="#" id="'+nome+'"><img src="' + images + '" width=90px height=120px></a></li>'); //Apply the images to the page, but the it dont recognise the id.

        });
    }
});

</script>
```

I know how to do to show the images in another div, but i need the ID (Right?).
I'm not a pro on Jquery and i want to thanks all the answers.

Comment: You do not need ID's to be able to show a clicked image in another div. Where is your markup and the destination div?

Comment: You can use jQuery DOM traversal functions, e.g. `$(this).child("img")` will get you the image inside the `<a>` that the user clicked on.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You do not need an ID to be able to show an image in another div. You just need to set up an event listener like the following:

```
$(function() {
    $('#ImageList').on('click', 'img', function() {
        $('#destination_div').html( $(this).clone() );
    });
});
```

[**WORKING JSFIDDLE DEMO**](http://jsfiddle.net/fiddleyetu/2f8S3/)

Comment: Thanks, this is definitly help me. 
I have another question,

Comment: Glad to know it helps. Let me know how I can be of further assistance.

Comment: Can you tell me how do i get the right size of each image i get?
Because this way it cant give me that.

Comment: Inside the handler above `$(this).width()` and `$(this).height()` should give you the size of the image just clicked.

Comment: Yeah, but it will give me the size of the image on the div and not the real size of it. I want to know the real size of each image in order to resize it on the right way.
I don't know if i'm being clear.

Comment: I'm not sure I understand what you mean. Can you create a jsfiddle? Perhaps that can help.

Comment: The firs half of my code above will put each image I have in a folder into a list.
Each image have his own size.
Once it put the image it will resize in order to put all at the same size.
Like if i want to decrease, lets say, 60% of the initial size.
Imagine that you have an image with 1024/480px and another with 480/1024, i dont wanna put both with 90/120px, i want to fit them in a imaginary box with 125/125px and deppending the size of each image, resize in order to fit there.
I can't be more clear.

Comment: If the images are 'unrestricted' where you're first adding them, you can capture their actual size by using something like this after dynamically adding img markup: `$('img').load(function() { $(this).data({'width':this.width,'height':this.height}); });` which will capture the size and store it in data attributes `width` and `height` where you can retrieve that from .... check this out: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/623172/

Comment: @TiagoBrites If you have another question you should create a new Question for it, not carry on a conversation in the comments.  There's also _chat_ if you do want a conversation.

Comment: Thanks @StephenP, and sorry about that.